# 90s cartoon TV show about a boy and a dimension hopping dinosaur

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

It's **NOT** *Denver the Dinosaur* I know that much.

All I remember is he could open portals to other dimensions/times(?) and kept showing up at the worst times and the kid was always keeping him hidden from his parents. I think he had blonde hair and I remember the animation looked fairly good for its time, modern/future-y sort of art style.

The dinosaur (or monster?) was green, fairly big, could obviously talk and tended to be a pain in the ass. I remember the kids house looked pretty cool too, super modern looking.

Comment: So far I have come up with a few, but none had a monster with "teleporting" abilities except from the TV series Mot. The show is about a monster who can teleport and ends up in a house with a kid, who he tends to get in trouble most of the time, since the parents dont have a clue about the monster. The monster isn't green, but purple (in the comics he used to be orange). I'll leave the link so you can see and check if it is. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot_(TV_series)

Comment: @HydraExiled I'm pretty sure you're on the money here. I'd say go ahead and make it an answer.